# SQL. How to add more values to a count() result?

Tags: sql

I have this situation:

a) talbe 'students' with students that contains their class/grade
b) tale 'outreach' with event that contains a class/grade and how many students were present

Now I need to produce a graph (with plotalot) that shows how many students per class/grade were reached.

I can get there for table 'studends' with a simple count() group by query. But how can I add the values of table 'outreach' to these results?

For example, tabel 'students' produces 45 entries for class 1. Table 'outreach' has two events for class 1 with 36 and 40 particiapants each. How to I get to 45 + 36 + 40 withoug having to run some loops?

I could sum them all up using th + operator between select statements, but isn't there a more elegant method?

Thanks for your suggestions!
Lori

Comment: tables' structures, sample data and desired output are highly welcome

Comment: Join then add. No loops required  Union is a possible option if the rows combine neatly.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, here are the basics of the table  structures:

Students

Bill / Class 1
Susan / Class 2
Marc / Class 3
Bob / Class 1
Ellen / Class 2

Events

Event 1 / Class 1 / 35 participants
Event 2 / Class 2 / 27 Participants
Event 3 / Class 1 / 31 participants

What I need is the total of class 1 (i.e. 1 + 1 + 35 + 31), class 2 (1 + 1 + 27), class 3 etc. etc.

I get the total of the 'students' table with count() and group by. But now, how to add the values from table 'events'?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Students
(
   NAME    VARCHAR2 (50),
   CLASS   NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO Students
     VALUES ('Bill', 1);

INSERT INTO Students
     VALUES ('Susan', 2);

INSERT INTO Students
     VALUES ('Marc', 3);

INSERT INTO Students
     VALUES ('Bob', 1);

INSERT INTO Students
     VALUES ('Ellen', 2);

CREATE TABLE EVENTS
(
   EVENT          NUMBER,
   CLASS          NUMBER,
   PARTICIPANTS   NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO EVENTS
     VALUES (1, 1, 35);

INSERT INTO EVENTS
     VALUES (2, 2, 27);

INSERT INTO EVENTS
     VALUES (3, 1, 31);

COMMIT;

--What I need is the total of class 1 (i.e. 1 + 1 + 35 + 31), class 2 (1 + 1 + 27), class 3 etc. etc.


--I get the total of the 'students' table with count() and group by. But now, how to add the values from table 'events'?

  SELECT CLASS, SUM (TOTAL) AS TOTALIZED
    FROM (  SELECT class, COUNT (1) AS TOTAL
              FROM STUDENTS
          GROUP BY class
          UNION ALL
            SELECT CLASS, SUM (participants) AS TOTAL
              FROM EVENTS
          GROUP BY class)
GROUP BY CLASS
ORDER BY CLASS;
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! I see I need to study some more SQL, especially the group by thing... Thanks a lot!